# Angular2 Router: Get Route for URL without navigating

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3, angular2-router

I want to display/hide `routerLink`s based on some `Data` from the router. The directive is done, but I'm missing the most essential part...

For example I have the following router config (omitted components):

```
[
  { path: '', children: [
    { path: 'foo', children: [
      { path: 'bar', data: { requiredPermissions: ['a', 'b'] } }
    ]}
  ]},
  { path: 'baz', data: { requiredPermissions: ['c'] }, children: [
    { path: ':id' }
  ]}
]
```

Now I'd like to ask the `Router` for the `Route` that would be used if the `routerLink` is `/foo/bar` or `/baz/123`.

I looked though the `Router` source code ( https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/router.ts ), but couldn't find some easy way to do this. Especially how it handles these `:id` variables.

Of course I could iterate over `Router.config`, going deeper and deeper. But then I'd have to parse those variables, regular expressions, etc. There must be an easier way, because the angular router must internally do all this stuff, too.

Do you have any idea / solution?

Comment: Di you want the data from the current route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fire `router.navigateByUrl`, wait for `RouteRecognized` event and cancel navigation (for example using custom Guard). `RouteRecognized` will have all necessary information. Obviously it is bad solution.

There is another approach, you could create additional structure (kinda map), that should contain path + data. For example structure has path `struct.baz-route={url:'baz/:id', perm: ['c']}`, then `[routerLink]="struct.baz-route.url.replace(':id', x)"`, then `*ngIf="struct.baz-url.perm.indexOf('c')>-1"`.

Answer (score -1):

hey if you want the data from current route than you can do like this to get that

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

export class Component {

   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
          let pathroots = this.route.pathFromRoot;
          let pathurl = '';
          pathroots.forEach(path => {

              path.url.subscribe(url => {
                   url.forEach(e => {
                      pathurl += e + '/';
                   });
              });


         });
         console.log(pathurl,'*******************');
       }

 }
```